# django mptt tag recursetree => is there any counter like forloop.counter or we have to declare a counter variable

Tags: django, django-mptt

We have forloop.counter for iteration in django template this is a built-in template operation.
Using this loop counter we can display the number and also utilize for various decisions of color or odd/even etc., UI work.

similarly, I am utilizing the recursetree of the django mptt tags, wondering any counter variable available.
or do we need to create a counter variable and increment for the display of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Answer:

1. CSS: Using CSS increment to display the sequence no. based on the Row Sequence -> display the no.
2. JS solution is also there

summary: could not find directly (from documentation) a builtin djangomptt counter variable like for loop template, may be using a custom tag / filter is not feasible, so switching to css alternative for now.